# Xamarin.Forms UWP doesn't compile, because of NETCore and other errors

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, uwp, xamarin.forms

I took a fresh auto-generated project and added basically this code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TestUWPFilePicker.UWP.FilePicker))]
namespace TestUWPFilePicker.UWP
{
    public class FilePicker : IFilePicker
    {
        public async Task<string> PickFolder()
        {
            var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            if (folder != null)
            {
                // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
                // (including other sub-folder contents)
                Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
                return folder.Path;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws me 42 errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    13  Active
Error   CS4036  'IAsyncOperation<StorageFolder>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<StorageFolder>' could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    16  Active
Error   CS1729  'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    8   Active
Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Users\some-user\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.2\ref\netcore50\System.dll' and 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\CSC  1   Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    17  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    8   Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    12  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    12  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    16  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    16  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    21  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    21  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    14  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    21  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    22  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported    TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    5   Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    12  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    21  Active
Error   CS1983  The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>    TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\App.g.i.cs 20  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\App.g.i.cs 31  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\App.g.i.cs 36  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\MainPage.g.i.cs    17  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\MainPage.g.i.cs    23  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'IList<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    14  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    14  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    16  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    17  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    21  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    21  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    22  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'Task<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    8   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Dependency' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    5   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DependencyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    5   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Task<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Tasks' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    2   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\FilePicker.cs    3   Active
```

and 13 warnings

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     A problem occurred while trying to set the "References" parameter for the IDE's in-process compiler. An item with the same key has already been added.  TestUWPFilePicker.iOS           
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android       1   Active
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   TestUWPFilePicker.iOS       1   Active
Warning     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.  TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'. TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  3   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.  TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.  TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'. TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\users\some-user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP
```

My UWP project has references to `System`, my PCL and `Universal Windows`. The PCL refers `.NET`, `Xamarin.Forms.Core`, `Xamarin.Forms.Platform` and `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml`. Min version is `Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)` and target version is `Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)`. `NuGet Package Manager` shows me `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` 5.2.2 installed (only UWP) and `Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.224`, despite it doesn't show up under UWP references.

If I uninstall and install `Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247` and want to deploy on my Windows Phone again I get only 6 errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Users\some-user\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.2\ref\netcore50\System.dll' and 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\CSC  1   Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\App.g.i.cs 20  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\App.g.i.cs 31  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\App.g.i.cs 36  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\MainPage.g.i.cs    17  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  TestUWPFilePicker.UWP   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.UWP\obj\ARM\Debug\MainPage.g.i.cs    23  Active
```

and again 13 warnings

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Could not copy "obj\Debug\TestUWPFilePicker.dll" to "bin\Debug\TestUWPFilePicker.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\TestUWPFilePicker.dll' because it is being used by another process.   TestUWPFilePicker           
Warning     Could not copy "obj\Debug\TestUWPFilePicker.dll" to "bin\Debug\TestUWPFilePicker.dll". Beginning retry 2 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\TestUWPFilePicker.dll' because it is being used by another process.   TestUWPFilePicker           
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android       1   Active
Warning     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.  TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'. TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  3   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.  TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.  TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'.   TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4   
Warning     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'. TestUWPFilePicker.Android   c:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker\TestUWPFilePicker.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.   TestUWPFilePicker.UWP
```

What is wrong with my references?

Currently, I have `Xamarin 4.5.0.443` and `Visual Studio 2015` installed. I tried to search for solutions for CS1703 without success. Now I tried to change the target profile, giving me again different errors (37) and warnings (11).

Comment: It references to `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlaform`, `Universal Windows` ,`Xamarin.Forms` and `YourPCLproject` in uwp default project. But I did not found `System` in my side. Please try to remove `System` reference.

Comment: In the meantime I updated to Xamarin 4.5.0.486, created the project again, removed `System` reference from UWP project and now it works. Thanks! You could post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update to `Xamarin` 4.5.0.486 and remove `System` reference from UWP client project.
[image]